# Undefined behaviour of GameCenter leaderboards with SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I tried to present leaderboards via this code block

```
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    }else{
            UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You must enable Game Center"
                                                              message:@"Sign in through the Game Center app to enable all features"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message show];
    }
```

And if I enabled all exception breakpoints, it will crash in the moment leaderboards are presented. When i delete this breakpoints, everything works fine. I am login into Game Center with test user. Is this a glitch or what ?

Comment: what crash, what exception message, where? Exception breakpoints halt when there is an exception, but the app may not be crashing if the exception is handled. Without more context the issue can't be solved.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It crashes on AppDelegates '@autoreleasepool' with objc_exception_throw in stack trace . And is marked as Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1.

Comment: That usually indicates you haven't added an exception breakpoint. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it via editing exception breakpoint from all to Objective-C exceptions . Tnx @LearnCocos2D for the answer